# Which fighter jet is this, based on the silhouette?

Tags: military, aircraft-identification, fighter, jet, uk

6 to 8 of these planes flew through the Ogwen Valley in North Wales, UK, this morning (2nd of June). Hawks and other training jets are common sights, but I’ve not seen these before and can’t identify the model. I thought F35s from the distinctive tail, but the wings are more swept back than the images of F35s I can find.

[image]

Comment: Good job on getting a crisp photo.

Comment: @BowlOfRed Got quite a few, and a video. After the first one shot by, I was ready to go.

Comment: Judging by the tail and its therefore [unnecessary wing(s)](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/99362/what-control-inputs-to-make-if-a-wing-falls-off).... The air intakes are a dead give away tho.

Comment: One of my favorites!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

What you've got there is a real life F-15! Love this aircraft, it's just got that quintessential military jet look about it.

There are 2 features which make it stand out

- The shape of the trailing edge of the main wings, straight and then angled
  [image]
- The shape of the tailplane, with those jagged leading edges
  [image]

Silouette of an F-15:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. Me and my mate actually worked it out in the end. I was only looking for planes operated by the RAF, but of course there are F15s stationed at Lakenheath.

Comment: Probably increasing operational frequency in anticipation of training Ukranian pilots.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri or even being flown by those Ukrainian pilots?

Comment: "it's just got that quintessential military jet look about it."  The F-86 Sabre is *the* fighter jet look (though maybe just for old people), with the F-4 Phantom a close second.

Answer (score 16):

That's a United States Air Force F-15E Strike Eagle, most likely one of those that are based at Lakenheath.

Comment: We reached the same conclusion in the end. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Looks like an F-15E Strike Eagle

- F-15 silhouette
- Twin seat
- Dark grey uniform paint scheme
- ‘Twin bagger’ ie 2 x 600 gal external tanks
- No missiles on the rails.
- Difficult to see if it has the FAST packs on the side of the fuselage
- Modern P&W F100 engine variant with the ‘turkey feather’ exhaust petals removed.
- Difficult to see from this angle the discerning features that separate it from an F-15D.

But…

- Most likely a Strike Eagle bubba out of Lakenheath doing some low level practice.